# fancybox 2.0.4 and Vimeo

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i have a lot of difficulties to integrate the new fancybox (V.2.0.4 g81c12d7) with the new iframe vimeo embed code.
does somebody have a  solutions?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the easiest way is to use the new vimeo's "[universal player](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/player)" to embed your videos.

Follow this steps:

A). From the vimeo page choose of one of your videos, then select the icon "`embed`" (over the video).

B). Get the `iframe` code that looks like:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/34792993?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

C). Extract the content of the `src` attribute and set it as the `href` of your link like:

```
<a class="vimeo" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/34792993?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0">open vimeo in fancybox</a>
```

D). Your fancybox (v2.x) custom script then should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".vimeo").fancybox({
  width: 400,
  height: 225,
  type: 'iframe',
  fitToView : false
 });
});
</script>
```

**Notice** I got the `width` and `height` from the `iframe` code.

**UPDATE** (Jun 25th, 2013) : another easier and simple way to watch vimeo videos in fancybox (v2.1.5 as today) is using the fancybox media helpers. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202629/1055987 for further reference.

Comment: I was having the same problem with the Shadowbox library (https://github.com/mjackson/shadowbox), and this answer fixed my problem as well (using the iframe URL for the link).

Answer (score 0):

Because we can only resize the iframe video if it is in our own domain, I solved this problem by copying all html content of

```
http://cache.vevo.com/m/html/embed.html
```

To `http://localhost/vevo.html`. Then, changed the CSS:

```
    #videoPlayerSWF {
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
    }
```

Now, I call fancybox url using:

```
http://localhost/vevo-embed.html?video=USUV71402745
```

Which has the same HTML, CSS, and JavaScript as:

```
http://cache.vevo.com/m/html/embed.html
```