# FancyBox Iframe not closing second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I know this question was asked before however I cannot get my code to work.

I have my fancybox initiated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('.fancybox').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        // hide the related video suggestions and autoplay the video
        'href' : this.href = this.href.replace(new RegExp("([0-9])","i"),'moogaloop.swf?clip_id=$1') + '&autoplay=1',
        'overlayShow' : true,
        'centerOnScroll' : true,
        'speedIn' : 100,
        'speedOut' : 50,
        'width' : 640,
        'height' : 480
    });
});

});
```

and then iframe is called:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://vimeo.com/123456">
```

But when I close popup and then try to open that again video is not showing up, could anyone help me to resolve it, most of solutions relates to 'type' : 'inline' and doesnt seams to work with my example.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using fancybox v2.x, then you don't need the (obsolete) options (v1.3.4) in your script. You could rather do

1). Set your html like

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://vimeo.com/123456">
```

... removing the special class `fancybox.iframe`

2). Add the helpers media js file like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

... set your path accordingly

3). use this script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            media: {}
        }
    });
});
```

... and save yourself some headaches.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e8nTZ/)**

You could add some more API options if you need them. Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs for the options of v2.x

Comment: Thank you JFK that works like a charm and my headache's gone ;) Thanks again

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me in I.E. The pop up show up but the video does not play.

Comment: @DavidMartinez :what is not working? the demos (jsfiddle) or your implementation. If the second, share a link to see what the problem is.

Comment: My problem is more complicated, the demo in http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs works fine in I.E, but if you go there, open the developer tools and change the Vimeo URL to my video (http://vimeo.com/65172210) then the demo doesn't work. I guess there is a problem with the video configuration in Vimeo, but I don't have access to the Vimeo account yet.

Comment: @DavidMartinez : here is working with your video http://jsfiddle.net/5BXbR/ don't see what the problem is or how come it's more complicated