# Fancybox not loading vimeo video

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, lightbox

I am having an issue with getting fancybox to load from my thumbnail. Currently it just goes straight to the website when clicked. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>      
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-      latest.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-4"><a class="fancybox" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/47429058"><img class="hoverme" src="images/1.jpg"/></a></div>
</body>
```

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202012/fancybox-iframe-not-closing-second-time/17202629#17202629

Comment: for more examples please check http://fancybox.net/vimeo